# How to view Azure AD schema

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I view the Azure Active Directory schema. 
Does Microsoft provides any document for Azure AD schema(similar to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx))?

I want to view all attributes of the User and Group in Azure AD with description. Similar document for Active Directory Domain Services is [Active Directory Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am currently exploring the Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph. I want to understand the difference between Active Directory Domain Services and Azure Active Directory with their attributes.

Also, does Azure AD has **USNChanged** attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is User in Azure AD Graph: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

And here is User in Microsoft Graph: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user

You can find the other entities like Group quite easily from there.